# How to tell ReSharper to sort usings with system namespaces NOT at the top?

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-2012

Visual Studio has an option to place system directives at the top when sorting them.

[image]

When this setting is **unchecked**, sorting using statements by right-clicking on them and using the *Organize Usings* feature, places System namespaces alphabetically along all other namespace imports.

However, ReSharper does not seem to honor this setting, nor does it have anything similar on its own Namespace Imports options page.  It always behaves as if you want System namespaces at the top.  This is especially annoying when you already have some at the bottom and you let ReSharper suggest a namespace to import, then you end up with some at both ends of the list.

Is there some way to fix this?  Or is this just a bug/oversight in ReSharper?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was testing this again under ReSharper 8 to see if it's been fixed, and I noticed something interesting:

- If my existing namespaces already have `System` items first, then ReSharper will insert new namespaces below them.
- If my existing namespaces have at least one item *before* the `System` items, then ReSharper will insert new namespaces alphabetically.
- ReSharper's behavior is the same *regardless* of the setting of Visual Studio.  It only takes into consideration the existing namespaces - *not* the setting of Visual Studio.

So if I have the following:

```
using A;
using System;
using Z;
```

Then if I use a class from namespace `B` and alt-enter to let ReSharper add the namespace, it will end up as:

```
using A;
using B;
using System;
using Z;
```

**BUT**, if I just have this:

```
using System;
using Z;
```

And I do the same exact thing, then I'll get:

```
using System;
using B;
using Z;
```

And it doesn't matter what VS's setting is.

I assume this is what was happening in ReSharper 7 also and I just didn't notice.

Comment: Im using r# 2017.2 and it seems that it's not working. Allways using is putted on the top.

Answer (score 15):

I am using ReSharper 7 and at least for me ReSharper takes the "System directive sorting option" from Visual Studio options.

Sometimes when VS and ReSharper settings get messed it helps to reset Visual Studio settings from Tool->Import and Export Settings->Reset all settings.

Comment: I've checked on multiple workstations, reinstalled, etc.  Resharper does not honor that VS setting when it is not checked.

Comment: @MattJohnson This is still true in current versions of Resharper (8.2). Resharper always places System directives first.

Comment: @MattJohnson I am seeing this as well, that sucks.

Comment: @JoeCartano - see my answer for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

If I cut all the usings, then I paste them where they were, and then do the sorting, it seems to respect the option:

`Place 'System' directives first when sorting usings`

I'm testing this on Visual Studio Community 2017 and Resharper 2018.3.4.

Answer (score 1):

**Versions: Resharper 2021.2 and VS Studio 2019 Professional**

The setting concerned with the issue was checked by default on Resharper:
[image]

However, this alone did not put 'System' usings first.

But upon checking the VS Studio setting, `Ctrl+R,Ctrl+ G` works as expected:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screenshot]

`ReSharper` | `Options` | `Code Editing` | `C#` | `Syntax Style` | `Reference Qualification and 'using' Directives` | `Place 'System.*' and 'Windows.*' namespaces first when sorting 'using' directives`

Deselect it.

See also this ReSharper help document: [Code Syntax Style: Namespace Imports - Configure namespace imports preferences](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Namespace_Imports_Style.html#style)

Answer (score -1):

### For ReSharper 2019.2.3

```
ReSharper -> Options -> Code Editing -> C# -> 
Code Style -> Reference Qualification and 'using' Directives
```

and then uncheck the checkbox

```
 Place 'System.*' and 'Windows.*' namespaces first when sorting 'using' directives
```